# Screen freezes right after login or if I move the mouse

Tags: login-screen, thinkpad

I just bought a thinkpad x1 carbon extreme (i7 16GB, 512GB) and I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS using a USB.

So the installation went smooth, and once I hit the login screen this is what happened

1. first time I entered my login and password, hit enter and the login screen goes away and its a blank screen with just the background and its frozen

   2. second time around after a hard reboot I enter my login and password, this time use the trackpad to click the login button and it froze
   3. third time I selected ubuntu with advanced options and did recovery mode and I was able to login and even install some packages etc.  Once I rebooted and tried normal boot it froze again.

What could the issue be here?

**Update**
When I boot ubuntu from my USB drive everything worked fine.  I was able to connect my wifi, download some packages and I did not notice any issues at all.

Comment: If this is a relatively new Thinkpad, you may have to run Ubuntu 19.10 to support the newer hardware. You could also check to make sure it has the latest BIOS... `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: [Lenovo's website](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/pd031426) says that x1 extreme laptops support Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the proprietary linux graphic drivers for your GPU, in your case, the `NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q`.

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> at your login screen to access your command line, *or*, you can boot into recovery mode and open the terminal.

Now run the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
```

You can now install the driver by running:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Alternatively, if you know the exact driver you need (probably `nvidia-390` for your card), you can run:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-(driver-number)$
```

If the installation is successful you can now run `sudo reboot` and use your laptop.